# Detecting app installation failures packagemanager

Tags: android, android-package-managers

My app needs to install few other apks and I need to exactly know when installation process completes. I am using below to detect package addition, replacement etc.

```
    <receiver android:name=".services.InstallReceiver">
        <intent-filter >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"  />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver
```

Sometimes app installations are failing (because sometimes they are system apps or greater version is already present etc).

Is there a way to detect these failures? logs have details of what happened but I am unable to get these details from packagemanager or InstallAppProgress.java..

```
W/InstallAppProgress: Replacing package:com.xxxx.xxxx
W/PackageManager: Can't install update of com.xxxx.xxxx update version 308 is older than installed version 312
D/InstallAppProgress: Installation error code: -25
I/InstallAppProgress: Finished installing com.diune.pictures
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Blockquote
>   Installation error code: -25

This error code identifies that you trying to install the older version of the package that is already installed.

Comment: How do you detect it?